# How to deploy symfony2 application?

Tags: php, symfony

As <kbd>parameters.yml</kbd> be? Here I have a repository of it is a clone, starts `composer install`. Of course there is only file <kbd>parameters.yml.dist</kbd>, well, after setting the parameters for the dependencies ask him, which by default will be empty. As a result - tests the database will not work

All that comes to mind - in <kbd>parameters.yml.dist</kbd> record the default settings to connect to the database and when you install it in rename parameters.yml, but the password to the database repository to store as something not kosher. What other options are there?

I use PHPCi.

Comment: You forgot to translate *pereimenovyvat* and *kosher*.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you follow these steps [Symfony2 deployment checklist](http://www.symfony2-checklist.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to look to the great deployment tool Capifony http://capifony.org/.  It will allow you make initial setup and place parameters.yml to shared config folder, that will be used for all other deploys

Comment: Due to Capifony being feature frozen it is recommended to use Capistrano v3 with the Symfony plugin (https://github.com/capistrano/symfony/) instead.